# session iphone - rails

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, session

I am using webservices to login from an iphone app.

I am not using sessions from the iphone app, but just communicating a random to authenticate data posted to the server over https.

Will the server create a session for each request from the iphone? Am I running into issues since the number of sessions on the server is going to get very high? I am not storing a lot of data in the sessions, but I guess the framework is. I am not sure how all that is running all together, and would like to be sure I am not building things upside down...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES, iPhone can handle session cookie, which simplifies my life greatly